# RC Car rolling resistance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

I am currently working on an RC car project and I am trying to find the rolling resistance of the vehicle. I am using the equation:

$T = V_s R_r/ \omega $

,where $T$ is driving torque, $R_r$ is rolling resistance, $V_s$ is linear speed, and $\omega$ is rotational speed. I have an experimental setup that will give me $V_s$ and $\omega$ already but I was wondering how I figure out the driving force? My first thought would be to measure the current output of the cars battery but I'm not sure where to find how that relates to the torque outputted by the motor.